# Finding webelement in 'Dojo' application using webdriver java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

HTML:

```
<div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
<input class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitValidationIcon dijitValidationInner" type="text" role="presentation" readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1" value="Χ "/>
</div>
<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
<input id="ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" name="ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value=""/>
```

From that I am unable to find the username using xpath in dojo.

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer']//input[@id='ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username']"));
```

Note: `autocomplete="off"` is mentioned.

Could you please describe little more. Below is my HTML.

```
<div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
<input id="ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" name="ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value=""/>
```

I tried `(//input[contains(@id,'LoginPane_username'))` but I am getting this error:

> "Unable to locate element:"

Is this error due to `autocomplete="off"` or because of dojo?

Comment: Dojo application's source is usually quite dynamic, don't rely on the ID of the elements. Try looking for other, static attributes - like the order of the elements. Try to look for the Nth input element for example.

Comment: Could you please describe little more. Below are my HTML code <div class="dijitReset dijitValidationContainer">
<div class="dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer">
<input id="ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username" class="dijitReset dijitInputInner" type="text" name="ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username" autocomplete="off" data-dojo-attach-point="textbox,focusNode" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" value=""/>

Comment: I mean not to use the full ID in your selector (the number can change anytime). Without seeing the structure of the webpage it is not easy. For example if it is the second input element on the website that's ID contains the word "LoginPane", you can do something like `(//input[contains(@id, "LoginPane")])[1]` (or similar - I use xpath rarely).

Comment: I tried (//input[contains(@id,'LoginPane_username')) this approach but I am getting error "Unable to locate element:" . is this error due to autocomplete="off" or because of dojo?please help me to find out the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try directly using id as below

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username"));
```

Or using preceding method using Xpath

```
//input[@id='ecm_widget_layout_NavigatorMainLayout_0_LoginPane_username']/preceding-sibling::div[@class='dijitReset dijitInputField dijitInputContainer']
```